# Hibernate OR criteria with null property

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a filter page for one of my Grails domain objects which has a single filter field that searches multiple of the domain fields. I have multiple `like(..)` filters inside a single `or` clause so that an object is listed if any of its fields match. One of the fields on the main object is another domain object, so the criteria code looks like:

```
    or{
            like("field1", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
            like("field2", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
            like("field3", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
            otherDomainObject{
                like("field4", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
            }

    }
```

When "otherDomainObject" is null, however, then the object isn't listed even if one of the other fields matches.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Associations in criteria is always an inner join, therefore the result set is discarded if association is `null`. Instead you can use [`LEFT_JOIN`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaSpecification.html#LEFT_JOIN)

```
import static org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN

...
or {
    like("field1", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
    like("field2", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
    like("field3", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")

    otherDomainObject( LEFT_JOIN ) {
        like("field4", "%" + params.generalFilterValue + "%")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use other CriteriaSpecification methods, but you must call it before left join:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

/* and here you could use 
 * 'resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP'
 *  if it's necessary */

or {
    ilike 'field1', "%${params.generalFilterValue}%"
    ilike 'field2', "%${params.generalFilterValue}%"
    ilike 'field3', "%${params.generalFilterValue}%"

    /* DRY?
    [1..3].each{
        ilike "field${it}", "%${params.generalFilterValue}%" 
    } */

    otherDomainObject(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
        ilike 'field4', "%{params.generalFilterValue}%"
    }
}
```